# Enabling GL2.GL_LINE_STIPPLE flip my lines

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to draw a dashed lines, so I added the following two lines

```
      gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
      gl.glLineStipple(1, (short) 0xf0f0);
```

Then all my lines were flipped horizontally ! any idea of the reason ?

Here an example of code :

```
// drawing the dashed lines 
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
    gl.glLineStipple(1, (short) 0xf0f0);
    final Color color = (Color) pline.getStrokePaint();
    gl.glColor4ub((byte) color.getRed(), (byte) color.getGreen(), (byte) color.getBlue(),(byte)( pline.getTransparency()*255));
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int i =0 ; i<  lineReference.getPointCount();i++) {
      gl.glVertex2d(lineReference.getX(i), lineReference.getY(i));
    }
    gl.glEnd();

// drawing the same lines but after disabling the dash mode 

    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int i =0 ; i<  lineReference.getPointCount();i++) {
      gl.glVertex2d(lineReference.getX(i), lineReference.getY(i));
    }
    gl.glEnd();
```

Here what I got :

[image]

Comment: It works fine in GLCanvas but not in GLJPanel

Comment: Maybe the build-in shader of the GLJPanel annoys you, have you tried to disable it? It has some minor side effects.